# Android WebView gets too slow simetimes, when I turn just my STB on

Tags: java, android, webview

I have a simple Android application which just contains a WebView to load my Web_Based application and a VideoView to play movie and Live TV.
Sometimes when I just turn my STB on, WebView loads the Web_Based application too slowly and sometimes fast.

My Web_Based application is in a local server (Ubuntu 12.04) and I can load this in my Computer Browser (Windows 10, Firefox and Chrome) fast Always. So I expect this happens in my Android Application fast Aslways.

I tried increasing the performance of WebView and also clearing Cache a lot. But it did not help at all.

```
// Here are some WebView settings

mWebView.clearCache(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(false);
mWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
mWebView.clearHistory();
mWebView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
    // chromium, enable hardware acceleration
    mWebView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
} else {
    // older android version, disable hardware acceleration
    mWebView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
}
```

Comment: When I install the APK (I mean just for the first time that the app is running), there is no any problem. But after that irregularly I see the problem. Maybe it is just because of Cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you have met all the requirements. So, in the next step, you must check the network connection with a tool such as PING.

If the connection between your android stb and host (web_based server) is not good and there are a lot of time outs, so the WebView can not respond well. So make sure about that.